# html tags not matching in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that contains an html document. I need to know if this string contains the substring `<title>Anmelden - Text</title>`. Unfortunately there are some new lines in the string, so that the string looks like this:

```
...
<title>
        Anmelden - Text
</title></head>
...
```

I have tried the following code:

```
var idx = html.search( /<title>\n*.*Anmelden.*\n*<\/title>/ );
```

But `idx` is always -1. If I remove the `<title>`and `</title>`the expression works.

I have used http://regexpal.com/ to verify my regex. There it works on my input.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use a regex for this. Create a DOM element and add the HTML string to it. Then, you can manipulate it like any DOM element, i.e. use `getElementsByTagName()` to get the title.

Comment: @Martin try `<title>[\S\s]*?Anmelden[\S\s]*?<\/title>`

Comment: Instead of searching for `.*`, use `\s|\S` or `[^]` or some such hack to match ANY character including newline.

Comment: @Avinash Your suggestion worked. If you post an answer instead of a comment I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @Amal Your suggestion will work of course, but I don't need anything else of the document. My suspicion would be that creating an html doc and looking for the title is much more overhead than the regex approach. Correct me please if I am wrong.

Comment: @Martin: If you care about overhead more than you do about correctness and accuracy, sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[\S\s]*` instead of `\n*.*` and `.*\n*` because there may be a possibility of spaces after the newline character. Note that `\n` matches only the newline character but `\s` matches all the space characters including newline `\n` , carriage return `\r`, tab characters `\t` also.

```
<title>[\S\s]*?Anmelden[\S\s]*?<\/title>
```